# ARM assemble Program Error- "This Register Combination results in unpredictable behaviour"

Tags: assembly, arm

I wrote a simple program to calculate factorial, but on compiling I am getting the error

```
    AREA PROGRAM, CODE,READONLY
    ARM
    ENTRY
    LDR R0,=0X5
    LDR R1,=0X1
    SUBS R2,R0,R1
AGN BLT OVR
    MUL R0,R0,R2
    SUBS R2,R2,R1
    B AGN
OVR END
```

> 7.1 Factorial calculation.S(9): error: A1477E: This register combination results in UNPREDICTABLE behaviour

I looked it up on ARM website, there examples

```
A1477E
This register combination results in UNPREDICTABLE behavior
This error is generated when you are assembling an instruction that has unpredictable results on execution. You must rewrite your code to avoid this unpredictable behaviour. For example, the following instructions all cause this error when assembling to 32-bit Thumb:
ADD sp, r0, #100 ; error - UNPREDICTABLE use of SP
CMP pc, #1 ; error - UNPREDICTABLE use of PC
PUSH    {r0, pc} ; error - use of an UNPREDICTABLE register combination
```

how is my code unpredictable in behaviour? MUL R0,R0,R2 to be specific. any ideas..?

Comment: Please don't write title in all-caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the arm arm (please read the arm documentation)...

Operand restriction

Specifying the same register for  and  was previously described as producing UNPREDICTABLE results. There is no restriction in ARMv6, and it is believed all relevant ARMv4 and ARMv5 implementations do not require this restriction either, because high performance multipliers read all their operands prior to writing back any results.

so you are likely building for an armv4 or armv5

Comment: thanks dwelch, but while choosing project in kiel uvision , I am selecting ARM7 as target,and now I learned the difference between ARM 7 & ARMV7 :)

Comment: Yep, that trips up a lot of folks, the marketing name for something and engineering name for something...Unfortunately arm marketing still uses numbers